# Routing Conventions in Can.js

Tags: canjs, canjs-routing

So I’m looking to make some routes within my super cool can.js application. Aiming for something like this…

```
#!claims          ClaimsController - lists claims

#!claims/:id      ClaimController - views a single claim
#!claims/new      ClaimController - creates a new claim
#!claims/:id/pdf  - do nothing, the ClaimController will handle it

#!admin           AdminController - loads my Administrative panel with menu
#!admin/users     - do nothing, the AdminController will handle it
#!admin/settings  - do nothing, the AdminController will handle it
```

So how might we do this?

```
“claims route”:      function() { load('ClaimsController'); },
“claims/:id route”:  function() { load('ClaimController'); },
“admin”:             function() { load(‘AdminController’); },
```

Cool beans, we’re off. So what if someone sends a link to someone like...

```
http://myapp#!claims/1/pdf
```

Nothing happens! Ok, well let’s add the route.

```
“claims/:id/pdf route”: function() { load('ClaimController'); },
```

Great. Now that link works. Here, the router’s job is only to load the controller. The controller will recognize that the pdf action is wanted, and show the correct view.

So pretend I’ve loaded up a claim `claims/:id` and I edit one or two things. Then I click the Print Preview button to view the PDF and change my route to `claims/:id/pdf`.

**What should happen**… the Claim Controller is watching the route and shows the pdf view.

**What actually happens**… the router sees the change, matches the `claims/:id/pdf` route we added, and reloads the Claim Controller, displaying a fresh version of the claim pulled from the server/cache, losing my changes.

To try and define the problem, I need the router to identify when the route changes, what controller the route belongs to, and *if the controller is already loaded, ignore it*. But this is hard!

```
claims      //
claims/:id // different controllers!

claims/:id      //
claims/:id/pdf // same controller!
```

We could just bind on the "controller" change. So defining routes like `can.route(':controller')` and binding on `:controller`.

```
{can.route} controller
// or
can.route.bind('controller', function() {...})
```

But clicking on a claim (changing from ClaimsController to ClaimController) won't trigger, as the first token `claim` is the same in both cases.

Is there a convention I can lean on? Should I be specifying every single route in the app and checking if the controller is loaded? Are my preferred route urls just not working?

Comment: Could you narrow this question a bit more?  This is a very broad question.  Perhaps split it in two.  One question for how to setup certain routes, another question for how to do progressive loading.

Comment: Also, I would avoid using routes in controls. It's an anti-pattern and will be removed in 3.0.

Comment: I know it's alot, I just needed to cover the use cases, lest someone give me a solution that doesn't think far enough ahead. I'll try to break it down. I can do progressive loading, I've got that sorted with requirejs. Can you link me to anything describing routing in a robust application? Or an article on why routes in controls is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is how I setup routing in complex CanJS applications.  You can see an example of this [here](https://github.com/bitovi/steal-can-example/blob/master/main.js#L54).

First, do not use can.Control routes.  It's an anti-pattern and will be removed in 3.0 for something like the ideas in [this issue](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/1216).

Instead you setup a `routing app` module that imports and sets up modules by convention similar to [this](https://github.com/bitovi/canjsmeetup/blob/master/7_route/can.app.js) which is used [here](https://github.com/bitovi/canjsmeetup/blob/master/7_route/can-app.html#L38).

I will explain how to setup a `routing app` module in a moment.  But first, it's important to understand how `can.route` is different from how you are probably used to thinking of routing.  Its difference makes it difficult to understand at first, but once you get it; you'll hopefully see how powerful and perfect it is for client-side routing.

Instead of thinking of urls, think of can.route's data.  What is in `can.route.attr()`.  For example, your URLs seem to have data like:

- page - the primary area someone is dealing with
- subpage - an optional secondary area within the page
- id - the id of a type

For example, `admin/users` might want `can.route.attr()` to return:

```
{page: "admin", subpage: "users"}
```

And, `claims/5` might translate into:

```
{page: "claims", id: "5"}
```

When I start building an application, I only use urls that look like `#!page=admin&subpage=users` and ignore the pretty routing until later. I build an application around state first and foremost.

Once I have the mental picture of the `can.route.attr()` data that encapsulates my application's state, I build a `routing app` module that listens to changes in `can.route` and sets up the right controls or components.  Yours might look like:

```
can.route.bind("change", throttle(function(){
  if( can.route.attr("page") == "admin" ) {
    load("AdminController")
  } else if(can.route.attr("page") === "claims" && can.route.attr("id") {
    load("ClaimController")
  } else if ( ... ) { 
    ... 
  } else {
    // by convention, load a controller for whatever page is
    load(can.capitalize(can.route.attr("page")+"Controller")
  }

}) );
```

Finally, after setting all of that up, I make my pretty routes map to my expected `can.route.attr()` values:

```
can.route(":page"); // for #!claims, #!admin
can.route("claims/new", {page: "claims", subpage: "new"});
can.route("claims/:id", {page: "claims"});
can.route("admin/:subpage",{page: "admin"});
```

By doing it this way, you keep your routes independent of rest of the application.  Everything simply listens to changes in can.route's attributes.  All your routing rules are maintained in one place.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! But that means I have to start using [`can.route.link`](http://canjs.com/docs/can.route.link.html). Do you have a helper you commonly use? **Edit** [Found them!](https://github.com/bitovi/canjsmeetup/blob/master/7_route/helpers.js)